# Azure Key Vault secret to store app users secrets

Tags: azure, security, cloud, azure-keyvault

In my application I have to store very sensitive data of its users, such as various password to other 3rd part services (user fill a form where he provides us login and password to 3rd part service)

The goal of the application is to setup other complex system using powershell scripts generated from over 100 inputs. There is a requirement to save user work as draft, and that is why I need to encrypt sensitive fields somehow.

I read a lot about Azure Key Vault and whenever I read about secrets it seems they are described to hold app settings rather then users secrets, so i am not sure if this is right to place those data.

Is Azure Key Vault secrets suitable for that job?

Moreover i am able to peek those value in azure portal as in plain text, and I want to avoid that. I suppose that I could encrypt them first and store already encrypted values, but this may be over engineering.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are describing as *user secrets*. If it's user credentials, then you need to federate login to an Identity Provider like Azure AD or Azure AD B2C. Key Vault is NOT an identity provider, but a secret store. If it's application secrets (think connection strings) then you should look at Key Vault (with [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity)).

Conversely, Application Settings (in App Service) are exposed in the Portal but are encrypted at rest. So if you're careful about who can access what within your subscription namespace, you should be just fine.

Comment: user secret : in our app user has a from where he types his user login and password to 3rd service.

Comment: we need to store those credentials

Comment: If that 3rd service is yours then use Azure AD as the identity provider. If it's not yours then you should reserach further options, like doing  OAuth with the 3rd party. Whatever you do, don't store user credentials, in any shape or form.

Comment: Unfortunately Azure AD and OAuth cannot be used. This is legacy system from 90's

Comment: Then what are you modernizing? Just wrap it all up in a VM and that's it.

Comment: This is not that simply. Our app creates powershells script to setup that system. To do that user has to fill a form with more then 100 inputs.There is a requirement where user can save his work as draft. And some inputs represents logins/passwords/clientIds etc to other services.