# Azure Functions, CosmosDB Trigger: How to store connection string in keyvault

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

The skeleton code for a CosmosDB triggered function is:

```
[CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "databaseName",
            collectionName: "collectionName",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "string",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]
```

`ConnectionStringSetting` is limited to being an AppSetting here.  I would like to go to key vault to grab this secret.

The comments for the attribute suggest that there is a way using CosmosDBOptions:

```
    /// Optional. A string value indicating the app setting to use as the CosmosDB connection string, if different
    /// than the one specified in the <see cref="CosmosDBOptions"/>.
```

but it's not clear how to use that class within the context of an Azure Function.

Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think it is possible for the moment. have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061388/azure-key-vault-secret-to-store-app-users-secrets/50061836#50061836. Also google `Cosmodb msi` you should find some useful link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the solution is available in Azure function

You can put your all keys, Secrets and Certificate into Key Vault and access via KeyValue URL (with Manage Identity). With manage Identity, you don't need to store KeyVault credential in your Azure function config.

[Key Vault Secrets in Azure Function with Manage Identity](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/key-vault-secrets-azure-function-manage-identity-pankaj-rawat/)

Answer (score 1):

The `CosmosDBOptions` refers to the configuration that can be set at the `host.json` level.

At the moment it is not possible to set the Connection String from Azure Key Vault, but it is a feature we'd like to include.